# How to call a function inside another?

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

How to call a function which has already been initialised, again ?
I have a search bar which searches for particular word and if it finds it, it changes a particular value.

```
var mover: String!
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
   let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latPass, longitude: longPass, zoom: 5)
   let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
   view = mapView

}
```

I want my `camera` to change value according to my `searchBar.text`

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print(searchBar.text!)

    if searchBar.text!=="test"{
        mover="test"

    }
}
```

The value of `mover` is changed, but how to refresh the camera view so it animates to particular coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is bad approach instaciating your mapView every time your CLLocationManager give some valid position, taking in account your current implementation, you must add a flag variable to execute the code inside your `didUpdateLocations` only once

**Code**

```
var mover: String!
var positionWasUpdated : Bool = false
@IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
{
   guard !positionWasUpdated else{
        return
   }

   let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: latPass, longitude: longPass, zoom: 5)
   let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
   view = mapView

}
```

After that when `searchBar` text is "test" you can use `.animate(to:)` method to animate the map to your new desired location

**Code**

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    print(searchBar.text!)

    if searchBar.text!=="test"{
        mover="test"
        if let mapView = self.view as? GMSMapView
        {
            mapView.animate(to: GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: yourDesiredLatitude,
                                                      longitude: yourDesiredLongitude, zoom: 15.0))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my desired lat and long are in `locationManager()`

Comment: I don't understand, you current code move always your map to the position reported by your CLLocationManager, what are you trying to do? can you explain a little more?

Comment: is there a way I can access the lat and long of `locationManager()` in my `searchBarSearchButtonClicked` ?

Comment: You can keep your last position reported as var and use it in my code

Comment: I retrieve my lat and long from firebase in my `locationManager()` and then when I search a particular name, I want it to animate it to the desired location, for which I need lat and long...which are in my `locationManager()`

Comment: locationManager only get your current location over and over again I think you are miss understanding the use of CLLocationManager, where is the code where you get the positions from your firebase?

Comment: I'm yet to write that code, but I think I'm confused. not sure where to write the code to animate the camera to particular coordinate.

Comment: you can use .animate(to:) as show in my answer to animate the map to any latitude and longitude @NaveenSaini